# How to get the column index value in gridview

Tags: asp.net

My `gridview` has `autogeneratecolumns = true` and I want to get the specific column index value of where the user click on the `gridview` cell. If the user clicks on the cell of third row, fifth column, then it will show the Header text of Third Row & Fifth Column. How can I get the specific column index value. Please help me out.

```
protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Label1.Text = "RowHeader - " + GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[0].Text + " and ColumnHeader - " + GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells[0].Text;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally I got it thru the following jQuery...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function () {
       $('#GridView1>tbody>tr>td').click(function () {
           var col = $(this).parent().children().index($(this));
           var title = $(this).closest("table").find("th").eq(col).text();
           $('p').html("Cell Clicked Text ---> " + $(this).text() + "<br/>" + "Column Name  ---> " + title + "<br/>" + " Column Index ---> " + col + "<br/>");
       });
   });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

General solution is:

`gridView.Rows['Index of selected row']['Index or column name of cell you want to get value from']`
that in concrete: 
`gridView.Rows[gridView.SelectedRowIndex]["ID"]`

As often values in cells are of type Object, so it needed to convert them after getting.
In some implementations it may be:
`gridView.Rows[gridView.SelectedRowIndex].Cells["ID"]`

But i think the main idea you have got.
Rows - are collection of rows of Table
and
Cells (or columns) - are collection of cells of Row

Reference from [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/614131/How-to-get-Column-Index-on-row-click-in-Gridview)

Comment: Yes. I already ready that article but how can I specify the column index value. How do we get the column index value dynamically.